# Pull name from Right of last "/"

Tags: excel

How do I pull the Manager name from the string below?  In my manager column I used the formula:

=RIGHT(A2,FIND("/",A2))

Help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","}}}",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))))+1,LEN(A2))
```

It will find the last "/" and get everything from 1 place to the right to the end of the string.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

Comment: beat you by 4 min. :P

Comment: @ScottCraner That you did :) However, the use of the =CHAR(number) function improves safety assuming the user defines an ASCII value that doesn't appear on the keyboard

Comment: I do not disagree, but I feel pretty safe that "}}}" will never show up in a folder or website name.  I like your use of it, and may use it in specific instances, but it is too easy to type "}}}" as they are right next to each other and is less typing than char(1).  But as you implied, there may be a time that "}}}" has the potential of being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the big `mid(), find(), substitute, len()` formulas needed to pull this, you could use a really light weight UDF:

```
Function strtok(strIn As String, strDelim As String, intToken As Integer) As String
   strtok = Split(strIn, strDelim)(intToken - 1)
End Function
```

Stick that in a new module in your VBE and then in your worksheet you can use:

```
=strtok(A1, "/", 5)
```

Which will grab the 5th token from `A1` split by a `/`

---

If the number of tokens in the string is variable, and you always want the last, instead you could use the UDF:

```
Function strlasttok(strIn As String, strDelim As String) As String
   strlasttok = Split(strIn, strDelim)(uBound(Split(strIn, strDelim)))
End Function
```

And call it like:

```
=strLastTok(A1, "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, because you're specifically getting everything to the right of the last instance of a charater:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```